# AWS EC2 Nginx Performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am using apache benchmark to measure the performance of nginx server installed in ec2 t2.medium instance.

When I run the apache benchmark from within the ec2 instance using private ip, I get these numbers:

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.042 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    1000
Total transferred:      608000 bytes
HTML transferred:       371000 bytes
Requests per second:    23633.40 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       4.231 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.042 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          14032.33 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.5      0       3
Processing:     0    4   2.3      4       8
Waiting:        0    4   2.3      3       8
Total:          0    4   2.2      4       8

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      4
  66%      5
  75%      6
  80%      6
  90%      7
  95%      7
  98%      8
  99%      8
 100%      8 (longest request)
```

When the same test is run from outside the ec2 instance using public ip, I get these numbers.

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   4.192 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Keep-Alive requests:    1000
Total transferred:      608000 bytes
HTML transferred:       371000 bytes
Requests per second:    238.53 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       419.240 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.192 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          141.63 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   25 198.3      0    2447
Processing:    66  200 269.3     91    2672
Waiting:       66  200 269.3     90    2672
Total:         66  225 360.2     91    3930

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     91
  66%     93
  75%    100
  80%    220
  90%    591
  95%    791
  98%   1354
  99%   1863
 100%   3930 (longest request)
```

It gives about 240 rps when tested outside ec2 using public IP while it gives about 23500 rps when tested from inside ec2 instance using private IP. The processing time between the two tests show significant difference. Please share your thoughts what could make the rps drop heavily.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check network connection between your load machine (which run the ab) and EC2 instance when you tested the public IP? m2.medium should support much higher than 141KBps

Comment: Load Machine has an 8Mbps line. I tested with another large static file served from nginx using the ec2 public ip and it could scale up to 500 Kbytes/sec. "Waiting: 66  200 269.3  90   2672" - time till first byte seem to be the issue. AB's transfer rate seem to be calculated from Total Transferred/Time Take for tests (608000/1024/4.192) and may not be indicating the actual data transfer rate.

Answer (score 0):

You have a large deviation in the connect phase which indicates package drops somewhere on the line. Using too many parallel TCP connections when you are already limited by bandwidth will cause package loss, which will then cause retransmission, increasing the effective latency.

Reduce concurrency to eliminate possible bandwidth problems. Also make sure that you don't run apache benchmark via wireless or any other half duplex technology, as this can cause additional latency or even package drop with high concurrency.

Answer (score -1):

It's old questions, but still most administrator are struggling to find the right answer for Nginx performance. Check below link for more details...

http://clouditops.blogspot.com/2016/11/improve-nginx-performance.html